# What do NORB and CIFAR stand for?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, image-processing, abbreviation

The [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is a standard benchmark data set of digit images.
MNIST stands for 'Mixed National Institute of Standards and Technology'.

The [NORB dataset](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~ylclab/data/norb-v1.0/) is a commonly used dataset of binocular images used in object recognition.

What does the abbreviation NORB stand for?

The [CIFAR dataset](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) is a commonly used dataset of RGB images used in object recognition.

What does the abbreviation CIFAR stand for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NORB = **NYU Object Recognition Benchmark**.
Source: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~yann/research/norb/.

CIFAR = **Canadian Institute for Advanced Research**.
Source: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/learning-features-2009-TR.pdf (page 32).

Comment: I have verified these abbreviations. Your searching skills seem better than mine. Thanks.